# C++ use if else

Tags: c++, if-statement, using

> (find maximum number among 5 number that are stored in variables and
>   show  1st maximum)

**
2nd maximum
 
**3rd maximum
**4th maximum
**5th maximum
using if else

what i have tried

```
{  int a,b,c,d;
   int w=0.0,x=0.0,y=0.0,z=0.0;
   cout<<"enter four numbers";
   cin<<a<<b<<c<<d;
   max= a<b||a<c||a<d||b<a||b<c||b<d||d<a||d<b||d<c;
   cout=max:
   max2= max>a||max>b||max>c||max||d;
   cout<<max2; 
  max3.....................................
  cout<<max3 
max4= max3<a||max3<b||max<c||max<d;
cout<<max4;<code>
}
```

Comment: Are you using `if` `else`? No, you're not. Apart from that, your code is far from valid.

Comment: `cout=max:` what is this?

Comment: Build your program step by step and try out each step. Only proceed if it works. For a start: cin >> a >> b >> c >> d; (so "arrows" the other way).

Comment: `max= a<b||a<c||a<d||b<a||b<c||b<d||d<a||d<b||d<c;` this will not give you a max value. it will give just `1` or `0`

Comment: `int w = 0.0, x = 0.0, y = 0.0, z = 0.0;` maybe you need float there?

Comment: Start by reading your compiler errors and warnings, and fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Please refrain from using namespace std;

```
{  int a,b,c,d;
   int w=0.0,x=0.0,y=0.0,z=0.0;
   std::cout<<"enter four numbers" << std::endl;
   std::cin>>a>>b>>c>>d;
int max = a;
   if (b > a)
max = b;
if ( c > max)
max = c;
if (d > max)
max = d;
  std::cout << max << std::endl;
}
```

I voluntarily kept trivial code that seems abordable for you and have left you space to now determine max2, max3 and max4.

Comment: This indentation is horrific.

Comment: And please refrain <g> from using `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of integers is fixed to 4 just:

```
max = a>b?(a>c?(a>d?a:d):(c>d?c:d)):(b>c?(b>d?b:d):(c>d?c:d));
```

Comment: The number of integers is fixed to **5**, and there's a requirement to use `if ... else`.

Comment: `int a,b,c,d;` & `cout<<"enter four numbers";` means 4. But I didn't notice the `using if else`. My bad.

Comment: The **problem statement** says 5. The code is wrong (although I didn't notice that until you pointed it out).